# Questions about Android Accessories on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a troubleshooting questions for a smart bracelet I've purchased, and would like to ask here.

I don't see in the Tour that it's strictly on or off topic. The device interfaces directly with my Android (although it's compatible with iOS as well, I don't have one of those), and not through a computer. The app to manage it is Android based.

Would asking questions about these other devices be on topic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems fine to me. There's a clear software component to the question, meaning that Android is (I can only assume) a relevant factor to the process. The fact that there is an app needed would lend more credence to this idea.

Where I would generally try to draw the line is: does something about Android *as software* have a meaningful impact? In cases where it's iffy then I think erring on the side of acceptance is certainly fine, but things that are likely to be considered off-topic are simply those where it is obvious that there are **not** any software considerations when using the accessory.

"How do I install a screen protector properly?" comes to mind as something that would fall into the latter (Android independent) category. Although instructions may vary between devices, it is not *Android*, the software, that causes that variance.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!